# What is the equivalent of passing an extra's dictionary to captureException in the new sentry-python SDK?

Tags: python, flask, sentry

What is the best way to pass extras to the new sentry-python SDK methods for capture_exception and capture_message?

Previously, I would:
`sentry_id = sentry.captureException(extra=extra)`

Based on the the docs and this github issue (https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/113), it like one of the below options is comparable, but I cannot figure out a way.

Using **capture_exception** is close...

```
except Exception as e:
    sentry_id = capture_exception(e, extra=extra) # Error
```

... but doesn't allow for a second extra's paramater :(

Using the **python logging integration** is very close...

```
except Exception as e:
    sentry_id = logging.error(e, exc_info=True, extra=extra)
```

... but doesn't return a sentry id :(

Using **both the python logging integration and capture_exception** is close...

```
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e, exc_info=True, extra=extra)
    sentry_id = capture_exception(e)
```

... but results in two separate error entries in sentry :(

Using **capture_exception with push_scope** is close...

```
except Exception as e:
    with push_scope() as scope:
        scope.set_extra(extra) # Error
        sentry_id = capture_exception(e)
```

... but doesn't accept a dictionary :(

Is the solution to use the last way, with a helper function which unpacks the extra dict into many `scope.set_extra(key, val)` calls?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
except Exception as e:
    with push_scope() as scope:
        for k, v in extra.items():
            scope.set_extra(k, v)
        sentry_id = capture_exception(e)
```

However, I would argue that you're setting `extra` at the wrong point in time. Ideally you would set your extra context data as soon as it becomes available and relevant to the code that is currently executing. Pushing a scope just to call `capture_exception` indicates a problem with the way you structure your calls to `set_extra`.

Instead of this:

```
logger.error("Event via logging", extra={"foo": 42})

try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    with push_scope() as scope:
        scope.set_extra("foo", 42)
        capture_exception()
```

Do this:

```
with push_scope() as scope:
    scope.set_extra("foo", 42)
    logger.error("Event via logging")

    try:
        1/0
    except Exception:
        capture_exception()
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I'm following. I must have a bad mental model of this. Thanks for your guidance! FWIW, for beginners like me, a "philosophy" of Sentry doc page would be helpful :) EG https://redux.js.org/introduction/threeprinciples

Comment: @craigmichaelmartin Noted. I am not able to come up with a better explanation right now but I'll keep in mind to write something into the docs.